# Server tries to connect to other servers

Tags: server, ssh, malware, vulnerability

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server and I have discovered in the `/var/auth.log` that it tries to connect to other servers.

This is the log file:

```
Aug 31 08:04:49 server_name sshd[16316]: error: connect_to 98.208.82.101 port 22: failed.
Aug 31 08:04:50 server_name sshd[16316]: error: connect_to 98.208.82.126 port 22: failed.
Aug 31 08:04:50 server_name sshd[16316]: error: connect_to 98.208.82.127 port 22: failed.
Aug 31 08:04:51 server_name sshd[16316]: error: connect_to 98.208.82.172 port 22: failed.
Aug 31 08:04:53 server_name sshd[16316]: error: connect_to 98.208.82.213 port 22: failed.
Aug 31 08:04:56 server_name sshd[16316]: error: connect_to 98.208.82.241 port 22: failed.
Aug 31 08:04:58 server_name sshd[16316]: error: connect_to 98.210.209.25 port 22: failed.
Aug 31 08:04:58 server_name sshd[16316]: error: connect_to 98.210.209.29 port 22: failed.
Aug 31 08:04:58 server_name sshd[16316]: error: connect_to 98.210.209.48 port 22: failed.
Aug 31 08:04:59 server_name sshd[16316]: error: connect_to 98.210.209.55 port 22: failed.
Aug 31 08:04:59 server_name sshd[16316]: error: connect_to 98.210.209.61 port 22: failed.
```

I have checked the server for vulnerabilities and everything is ok. The ssh was not configured properly until today.

I've also ran a virus scan and nothing is infected.

What else can I check?

Answer (score 0):

i've discoverd the issue. We were hacked and a user made attempts on other servers.

They used a vulnerability in the Nagios configuration that allows the "nagios" user to make logins. We disabled logins for this user and killed the process that was making the attempts

Comment: HI Mihai
how did you figured out u were hacked ? we are having simialr kind of scenario